# ColorPrimary,colorAccent replaced in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

i have a style in android studio project now I want use this to eclipse project but make error

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and want use this sdk

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

error is

> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'colorPrimaryDark'.
>
> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'colorAccent'.

Comment: Can you please add error details ?

Comment: @soumyasambitKunda error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.

Comment: make sure that the appcompact files are available in appdata folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Update the project.properties file of appcompat v7, which has:target=android-19 to target=android-21
2. Also update google play services library (by update I mean update it in SDK Manager and re-import etc)
3. Fixed the issue for me. The appcompat_v7 project was targeted at 4.4.2 so it failed to link the v21 libs.